# How to simulate the opening of the second tab in a browser and test the behavior of a react component in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

We are using a token-based authentification and, in some cases, keep token in sessionStorate. When a user opens a new tab, we copy this token from any other opened tab and reload the user object.
All this logic lives in a component  that wraps everything else:

```
export const App = (): JSX.Element => (
  <AppPreloader>
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Routes />
    </Provider>
  </AppPreloader>
);
```

The component AppPreloader:

```
import React, { FC, useState } from 'react';
import { useEffectOnce, useUpdateEffect } from 'react-use';
import { getAnyToken } from '../../../redux/auth/auth.utils';

export const AppPreloader: FC = ({ children }) => {

  const persistToken = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
  const anyToken = getAnyToken(); // check if any token exists
  const [isPrepared, setIsPrepared] = useState(!!anyToken);

  // if token is in localStorage we skip all this
  if (!persistToken) {
    window.addEventListener('storage', event => {
      const token = window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');
      
      // this part is trigered on every tabs but executed only where token exists
      if (event.key === 'REQUESTING_SHARED_CREDENTIALS' && token) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('CREDENTIALS_SHARING', token);
        window.localStorage.removeItem('CREDENTIALS_SHARING');
      }
      // this part is executed after CREDENTIALS_SHARING event and only executed in tabs where token doesn't exist. This part recreate token in the new tab in sessionStorage.
      if (
        event.key === 'CREDENTIALS_SHARING' &&
        !token &&
        event.newValue !== null
      ) {
        window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', event.newValue);
        setIsPrepared(true);
      }
      if (event.key === 'CREDENTIALS_FLUSH' && token) {
        window.sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
      }
    });
  }

  // when component is mounted we trigger event in localStorage and this event appears in all tabs simultaneously
  useEffectOnce(() => {
    if (!persistToken) {
      window.localStorage.setItem(
        'REQUESTING_SHARED_CREDENTIALS',
        Date.now().toString(),
      );
      window.localStorage.removeItem('REQUESTING_SHARED_CREDENTIALS');
    }

    const timeOut = setTimeout(() => setIsPrepared(true), 200);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeOut);
  });

  useUpdateEffect(() => {
    anyToken && setIsPrepared(true);
  });

  return <>{isPrepared ? children : <div>LOADING TOKEN</div>}</>;
};
```

I try to do something like:

1. render element
2. set in sessionStorage token
3. create new session
4. render element here
5. check if token exists in new sessionStorage.

Any idea how to do it? I can't simulate the behavior of 2 open tabs in jest.

Comment: How did you end up solving this problem?